# Writing integration tests for Apache Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

What is the recommended way of writing integration tests for a Apache Storm topology in Java? Appreciate any suggestions/links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LocalCluster for integration testing. Take a look at this class https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/822a4685c0278aba9d4e0f43104bc4f86a462222/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/LocalCluster.java#L119

You can look at some of Storm's own integration tests for inspiration e.g. https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/e0feb6cf04107029d4b24420f265495cdfbdb098/storm-server/src/test/java/org/apache/storm/TestingTest.java#L38.

Tools you may want to use are the `FeederSpout` and `FixedTupleSpout`. A topology where all spouts implement the `CompletableSpout` interface can be run until completion using the tools in the `Testing` class.

Storm tests can also choose to "simulate time" which means the Storm topology will idle until you call `LocalCluster.advanceClusterTime`. This can let you do asserts in between bolt emits, for example.